# Get PM or AM from string date C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, date

I have this string as a date and I want to add the AM/PM to the end.

From
10-17-2018 00:00:00

To
10-17-2018 00:00:00 AM

How is possible? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried?  What _specifically_ is not working?

Comment: Where does the string come from? Is it originally from a `DateTime` instance? If so that would be the place to add formatting to also output AM/PM. Do you have a DateTime to begin with and is this not really a string? If so then do no t worry about it until it reaches the presentation layer. What about the 00:00:00? Is it always at this time? In that case why even bother with AM/PM or trying to add logic to figure out what to add?

Comment: Also remove either [tag:vb.net] or [tag:c#] tag, I doubt you want answers for both.

Answer (score 1):

So convert the string date into a real DateTime, then ToString() it back out in the format you like:

```
var dateStr = "10-17-2018 00:00:00";
var date = DateTime.Parse(dateStr);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"));
```

Output: 10-17-2018 00:00:00 AM

DateTime formats: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: Why is this better than just adding "AM" or "PM" to the string?  OP has seemingly indicated they have a source string, if OP has a `DateTime` instance then modifying that and calling `.ToString()` is the obvious approach but OP has provided zero detail.

Comment: I'm guessing OP has the first date as a string coming from outside their control, in which case they wouldn't know which "AM" or "PM" is correct to be added.

Comment: @maccettura - I think the question itself is a bit unclear in that regard. I don't see any indication that OP has a `DateTime` already, so this is a fairly "safe" answer IMO.

Comment: If the OP indeed has it as a date to begin with, then the final line in my code block shows how to get the AM/PM via the "tt" format-string.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb which is why its best not to answer questions that have zero detail.  The title says "Get PM or AM", yet the body asks how to concatenate strings.  We have no idea what the OP wants so the question should be closed until its made fit.

Comment: Your code raises an exception at Parse moment.
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." Btw I tried this before.

Comment: @CarlosAB It runs fine on my machine, using the C# interactive window in Visual Studio 2017.